# TYPO3 - How to overwrite the template path in a backend core extension? (filelist)

Tags: typo3, overwrite, typo3-8.x

I need to overwrite the template files under
htdocs/typo3/sysext/filelist/Resources/Private/Templates/FileList
Specially htdocs/typo3/sysext/filelist/Resources/Private/Templates/FileList/Search.html

I have created copied and modify the file in:
myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates/Search.html

Typo3 8
Reading the information in :
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/2-Backend-modules.html

This is what i tried:

```
module.file_FilelistList {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates/
        }
    }
}

module.FilelistList {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates/
        }
    }
}

module.filelist {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates/
        }
    }
}
```

and also

```
module.tx_file_FilelistList {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates
        }
    }
}

module.tx_FilelistList {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates
        }
    }
}

module.tx_filelist {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            100 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Extensions/sysext/filelist/Resources/Templates
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working. What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

**Never ever change any files from core or external extensions.**

You will loose the option to do regular updates.

You can build your own version of those files and add the path to these files in the typoscript so your files are preferred to the default files.

You just need to identify the settings to add your path.

Comment: This is what I want. Overwrite the paths and use my own Fluid Template. But How?